# last image of the slide jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying mo make a slide that, when the last image shows, the 1st image will slide next to the last image.

but what I got on the result of my code is, when its in the last image, the first image just blink..

here,s my code.

```
var sliderUL = $(".slider").css("overflow", "hidden").children("ul")
    imgs = sliderUL.find("li"),
    imgWidth = 913,
    imgsLen = imgs.length,
    current = 1;

setInterval(function(){
    sliderUL.animate({"margin-left": "-=" +imgWidth},1000, function(){
        current ++;
        if (current === imgsLen) {
            current = 1;
            sliderUL.css("margin-left", 0)
        };
    });
},3000);
```

Comment: Can include `html` , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: here please take a look. https://jsfiddle.net/ian_online/zap44sxh/embedded/result/